# How do I use login session in angular2 (local storage) with php backend

Tags: angular, jwt

This is `login.component.html` file

```
<form method="POST" [formGroup]="LoginForm" (ngSubmit)="doLogin($event)" >
  <div class="imgcontainer">
    <img src="assets/images/flat-avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <label><b>Email</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" formControlName="email">

    <label><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" formControlName="password">

    <button type="submit">Login</button> 
  </div>
</form>
```

this is the  login component (`login.component.ts`) file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators,FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { FORM_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/common';
import {AuthenticationService} from  './authentication.service';
import {CanActivate, Router,ActivatedRouteSnapshot,RouterStateSnapshot}  
from '@angular/router';

@Component({
moduleId: module.id,
selector: 'login-cmp',
templateUrl: 'login.component.html',
styleUrls: ['login.css'],
providers: [AuthenticationService],
directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class LoginComponent {
  loginData : myData [];
  public LoginForm = this.reg.group({
      email: ["", Validators.required],
      password:["",Validators.required]
      });
  constructor(public reg: FormBuilder, private _service :  
  AuthenticationService ,  private router: Router ) {}
  doLogin(event) {
  this._service.dataLogin(this.LoginForm.value).subscribe(
        loginData => this.handleResponse(loginData),
        error => this.handleResponse(error)
        );
    }
 handleResponse(response) {
 if (response[0].data == 'error') {
              alert('error');
 }
 else{
 this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/home']);
      }
   }
 }
interface myData {
 data : string;
}
```

I have use the `authenticate.service.ts` file for getting the data in providers section

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http,Response,Headers,RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Routes} from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService
{
constructor(private _http:Http) {}
private _contactUrl = 
'http://localhost/proj2/src/databaseFiles/empLogin.php';

dataLogin(newlogin: Login): Observable<string>{
 let body = JSON.stringify({
 email: newlogin.email,
 password: newlogin.password
 });


 let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
 let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
 return this._http.post(this._contactUrl, body, options).map(res => <string> 
 res.json());
 }
private handleError (error: Response) {
console.error('Error in retrieving news: ' + error);
return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
 }}
```

And finally the response coming from php file in json form if data matches in database.

```
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0){
 $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
 $response_array[]['data'] = $row['emp_id'];
 echo json_encode($response_array);
 }
 else{
 $response_array[]['data'] = 'error';
 echo json_encode($response_array); 
 }
```

so, how do i use the session in it and pass it to the component and maintain the emp_id through out the navigation

Answer (score 0):

In your `logincomponent.ts`

```
doLogin(event) {
  this._service.dataLogin(this.LoginForm.value).subscribe(
        loginData => {
            this.handleResponse(loginData);
            localStorage.setItem('emplyeeId', 'emp_id');
          },error => this.handleResponse(error)
        );
    }
```

Note that you will need to add "dom" to the "lib" array in your `tsconfig.json` if you don't already have it.

Comment: i am running this project on wamp not on node server. do i have to use JWT or any other classes to import for it?